# NodeRed catalogue hosted on Azure Artifact

Tags: node.js, azure, node-red

I've been trying to add a custom catalog to my Node-RED installation using an npm feed hosted on my Azure DevOps instance. I looked everywhere for documentation, including [this](https://github.com/node-red/node-red/wiki/Design%3A-Palette-Management-UI#customising-the-catalog), I'm encountering difficulties getting it to work.

Here's a snippet of the configurations I've tried in the settings.js:

```js
 editorTheme: {
        projects: {
            // To enable the Projects feature, set this value to true
            enabled: false
        },
        externalModules: {
            autoInstall: false,
            autoInstallRetry: 30,
            palette: {
                allowInstall: true,
                allowUpload: true,
                allowList: ['*'],
                denyList: []
            }
        }
    }
```

or this

```js
  // Customising the editor
    editorTheme: {
        projects: {
            // To enable the Projects feature, set this value to true
            enabled: false
        },
        palette: {
            editable: true, // Enable/disable the Palette Manager
            catalogues: [   // Alternative palette manager catalogues
                'https://catalogue.nodered.org/catalogue.json',
                'https://dev.azure.com/myorg/myOtherCatalogue.json'
            ]
        },
    }
```

For reference, I'm using Node-RED version 3.1.5 and npm version 10.4.0.

If anyone has successfully set up a custom catalog in Node-RED using an npm feed on Azure DevOps or has any insights into what might be causing the issue, I would greatly appreciate your help.

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: What problem are you actually seeing? Do you see the new catalogue listed in the palette manager? Do you see any errors in your browser console? The important thing to remember is that this URL is loaded by the browser not the NR runtime. There isn't a distinct answerable question here

Comment: @hardillb I don’t see any additional catalogue in the palette manager

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution.

This is the new configuration inside `editorTheme`:

```js
editorTheme: {
        projects: {
            // To enable the Projects feature set this value to true
            enabled: false
        },
        palette: {
            catalogues: [   // Alternative palette manager catalogues
                'https://catalogue.nodered.org/catalogue.json',
'https://dev.azure.com/myorg/myOtherCatalogue.json'

            ]
        },
    }
```

Comment: Also there appears to be no difference between the JSON in this answer and your question

Comment: But what's happening with StackOverflow. Instead of helping others, it's just a hunt on people questions. Btw, if you looked better, there is a difference. First, I told which one is the right to use, second, I removed a DEPRECATED item, `editable: true` that seems to be the problem

Comment: My point was to get you to update the answer with why something you had said didn't work in the question, now works. (I have tested with and without `editable: true` and both work).  p.s. this may be of use to you https://github.com/hardillb/node-red-private-catalogue-builder while written to run against vedaccio it should work against any npm repo if you can get the authentication working.